# Inter-process Communication for Apache Server and Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver, ipc

For Nginx and Apache httpd web server, there usually exist several processes there for certain modes. For example, there is a master process and several worker processes.

How these processes communicate with each other? It seems that they use a file to communicate. I do not know if it is right and need further explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx uses [Unix domain sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) to communicate with the workers. You can [see them being created](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/os/unix/ngx_process.c#L117) and [being](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/os/unix/ngx_process_cycle.c#L448) [written](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/os/unix/ngx_process_cycle.c#L520) [to](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/os/unix/ngx_process_cycle.c#L611) and [read from](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/os/unix/ngx_process_cycle.c#L1025) in the nginx source.

Comment: Does it use any shared memory or signal to communicate among workers?

Comment: Nginx does not use shared memory for communication among its ownprocesses, although shared memory facilities are available for module use. Signals are not used to regularly communicate with children. On shutdown, it may send a KILL signal to a child process should it not exit by itself after a second.

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Comment: Any comments about Apache?

Comment: [_Apache's parent and children communicate with each other through something called the scoreboard. Ideally this should be implemented in shared memory. For those operating systems that we either have access to, or have been given detailed ports for, it typically is implemented using shared memory. The rest default to using an on-disk file._](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/perf-tuning.html)

Comment: I also noticed this. But when I run my Apache/Nginx server, and use the "ipcs -a" command to show the System V IPC status, there is no shared memory. Actually nothing is shown by the command.

Comment: That'll only show you the SysV shared memory usage and won't tell you about `mmap` shared memory should that exist. If you're on Linux, you can look at `/proc/[pid]/smaps` to get the mmap shared memory mappings.

Comment: It appears that Apache maintains sockets between parent and children. I'm able to see shared sockets in the `lsof` listing on a Linux server running Apache.

Comment: Basically, "mmap shared memory mapping"   is to read/write from/to the same file, right?

Comment: It's actually reading/writing to shared memory, same as if it were unshared (i.e. allocated by `malloc`). In this case, it's set up with the `mmap` call, which is a separate interface from SysV shared memory that `ipcs` will tell you about. `mmap` [doesn't necessarily have to associate the memory with a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap#File-backed_and_anonymous).